# Remove each last element of nested array and complete last array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

There is an array with multiple array. My aim is to build a html-table with this data. Therefore the length of each array must be the same.

Now I want to remove empty rows or colomns: If all last elements of each array are empty (=empty string) or the last array has only empty string, they should be removed.

So this

```
var data = [
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '' ],
    [ '', '', '' ]
];
```

should become:

```
var dataNew = [
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2' ]
];
```

This is what I got so far:

```
data = removeEmpty(data);

function removeEmpty(data) {
    // check for empty colomn at the end
    var colHasValue = false, 
        len = data.length;

    while (len--) {
        if (data[len][data[len].length - 1]) {
            unchanged = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!colHasValue) {
        data = data.map(function (v) {
            return v.slice(0, -1);
        });
    }

    // check for empty row at the end
    var rowHasValue = false,
        lastArray = data[data.length - 1],
        len = lastArray.length;

    while (len--) {
        if (lastArray[len]) {
            hasValue = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!rowHasValue) {
        data.pop();
    }
    return data;
}
```

This is working so far. But what should I do if there are two empty rows or colomns at the end?

Example:

```
var data = [
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '', '' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '', '' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '', '' ],
    [ '', '', '', '' ],
    [ '', '', '', '' ]
];
```

should become:

```
var dataNew = [
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2' ]
];
```

**Update:**

In this case nothing should be done to the array, as the last col/row aren't completely empty:

```
var data = [
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '', '' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '', 'content' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', 'content', '' ],
    [ '', '', 'content', '' ],
    [ '', 'content', '', '' ]
];
```

Comment: Why do I get a downvote for this - as I think - detailed description, examples and my own attempt?

Comment: What if the empty column/row is the first? Should it be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by combining `Array.prototype.map()` with `Array.prototype.filter()`

```
var dataNew  = data.map(function(a){
  return a.filter(function(b){
    return b.trim().length;
  });
}).filter(function(itm){
    return itm.length;
});
```

Edit:

```
var dataNew = data.filter(function(itm){ return itm.join("").length; }), internalCnt;
for (var i = 0, len = dataNew.length; i < 4; i++) {
  for (var j = 0, cnt = 0; j < len; j++){ if(dataNew[j][i] == ""){ cnt++; } }
  if(cnt == len) {
   internalCnt = 0; 
   while(internalCnt < len){ dataNew[internalCnt].splice(i,1); internalCnt++; } i--;
  }
}

console.log(dataNew);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/htvdsgat/2/)

Comment: I would have achieved this in 500 lines. ;)

Comment: This won't work. Please look at the updated example. If any row or column doesn't have a 'full' dataset, the structure will be messed up.

Comment: @user3142695 What is the expected result for your updated example?

Comment: @VenomVendor I did not down vote... and I did the update transparent

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy In the updated example the result will keep exact this array. It should just be modified if a row or column is **completly** empty. Do you understand, what I mean?

Comment: @user3142695 Yeah understood your problem. Working on it. give me few mins

Comment: @user3142695 Fixed the issue that you mentioned. check out the recent edit.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Oh wow. Awesome. You are the greatest.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I think this case doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/htvdsgat/3/ Shouldn't the last column be removed as the last element of both remaining arrays are empty?

Comment: @user3142695 I have hard coded the column length. Fixed it. https://jsfiddle.net/htvdsgat/5/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it: Using map, we go through each array, then filter out the empty strings, then finally filter out the left over empty arrays.

[Working Fiddle for the code below](https://jsbin.com/wubacuw/1/edit?js,console)

```
var data = [
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '', '' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '', '' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '', '' ],
    [ '', '', '', '' ],
    [ '', '', '', '' ]
];

var newArray = data.map(function(el) {
  return el.filter(function(a) {
    return a !== '';
  });
}).filter(function(el){
  return el.length > 0;
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this would mess up the structure. Example: Replace the second array with: `[ 'field 1', 'field 2', '', 'content' ]`.

Comment: well it answered the question until you edited it just now, will delete

Answer (score 0):

A small pivot will help with [`Array#reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRigth), for going backwards and a check with [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) if the row is not completely empty and then add the data to the result array.

Apply twice for the right orientation.

```js
function killEmpty(array) {
    function pivot(array) {
        var empty = false;
        return array.reduceRight(function (r, a, i) {
            empty = empty || a.some(function (b) {
                return b;
            });
            empty && a.forEach(function (b, j) {
                r[j] = r[j] || []
                r[j][i] = b;
            });
            return r;
        }, []);
    }
    return pivot(pivot(array));
}

var data = [['field 1', '', 'field 2', ''], ['field 1', '', 'field 2', ''], ['field 1', '', 'field 2', ''], ['', '', '', '']],
    data2 = [['field 1', 'field 2', '', ''], ['field 1', 'field 2', '', 'content'], ['field 1', 'field 2', 'content', ''], ['', '', 'content', ''], ['', 'content', '', '']];

document.write('<pre>pre ' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>post ' + JSON.stringify(killEmpty(data), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<hr><pre>pre ' + JSON.stringify(data2, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>post ' + JSON.stringify(killEmpty(data2), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```